# Is there a replacement for /dev/random on Android JNI?

Tags: android, random, cryptography

I have a written an application which generates an ECDSA public/private keypair via OpenSSL 1.0.1c. 
From what I understand, OpenSSL uses /dev/random on Linux, but Android does not have /dev/random which means I could potentially be serving cryptographically weak keypairs.

I read both this

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/do-mobile-oss-provide-crypto-quality-randomness

and this question

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14669/how-to-select-dev-random-or-dev-urandom-in-the-code-in-android

and both do give adequate suggestions for using `java.security.SecureRandom`, however I generate these keypairs on the native side, so something native is welcome. I can pass arguments from Java to my native code, so it's easy to pass in the random bytes, however if there is at all a way to do it entirely on the native side, I choose that.

So, is there a replacement for /dev/random on Android?

Comment: My C tag was adequate, since I generate these keypairs on the native side using C and OpenSSL. I have also stated JNI in the question title.

Comment: Why revert to OpenSSL/JNI if you can use e.g. Bouncy Castle? ECDSA key pair generation should be plenty fast and `SecureRandom` is properly seeded (if you don't seed it before generating randoms).

Comment: I use SpongyCastle, and I can tell you, it's slow. I need JNI for the speed.

Answer (score 4):

Android provides both `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` to native code. Both are world readable. You should use `/dev/urandom` because Android already makes sure the PRNG is seeded.

The only advantage of `/dev/random`/ over `/dev/urandom` is that `/dev/random` is safe even if the PRNG isn't seeded. But Android always seeds the PRNG. So there's no advantage. And `/dev/random` has huge disadvantages -- it depletes the system entropy pool.

Comment: The answer in this question http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14669/how-to-select-dev-random-or-dev-urandom-in-the-code-in-android states that there is no /dev/random on Android, assuming I understand it correctly. And /dev/random is preferred over /dev/urandom since it is cryptographically sound.

Comment: @owlstead: I added it to the answer and deleted the comment because of that error. Thanks.

Comment: @farmdve `/dev/urandom` is secure if it was sufficiently seeded. The main issue with it is that some implementations are broken and don't block until it has been seeded. But AFAIK Android guarantees that it seeds sufficiently.